# Scala Slick sum()

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Currently I have a PostgreSQL query which calculates expression:
`SELECT sum(timestamp2 - timestamp1 [some other math]) from <...> WHERE <...>`.

Is there a way to do it with Slick? I tried to fetch raw data (login and logout) from database and process it, but this method is too expensive, so I need to process data on the database side.

Comment: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#aggregation

Comment: Go ahead and say that question title five times fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do calculated columns

https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1314

So in your case it will be

```
def ts(row: YourTableClass[_]) = row.timestamp2 -- row.timestamp1
```

Next you can do aggregation like shown in nmat's link